# "No object of java.lang.Objects could be found in heap snapshot" in JProfiler

Tags: java, class, memory-leaks, jprofiler

I am new to JProfiler. I am leaning this software to give a presentation. I run the class file by starting a new session. JProfiler displayed all classes on the dynamic live memory screen. However, when I tried to show in heap walker, a error message dialog box appeared.

Which says...
"No objects of java.lang.Objects could be found in heap snapshot"

java.lang.Objects is the class the i tried to view in heap walker.

Can anyone please let why is this showing and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want java.lang.Object

the other class is a utility class with methods for manipulating objects.

Answer (score -1):

Your object might be having a null reference which is eligible for GC. So, heap walker view might not be displaying it as its memory will be freed soon.

Comment: Are you just assuming or talking from experience? I have exactly the same error and i have a leak. I can clearly see its references are not going to be freed anytime soon.